# How to select a portion of an image and save just that portion to a file

Tags: java

I am taking a screenshot of the current screen then saving the image. I want to open that image up and be able to select a box of a certain element or whatever it is i want the pic to be of and to be able to in turn save that smaller selected image to 
 a file. Please help.

RemoteControlConfiguration config = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
        config.setPort(4447);

```
    SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(config);
    try{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    server.start();

    DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4447, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.open("http://www.google.com/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
    selenium.windowMaximize();

    BufferedImage image1 = Screenshot("screen1.jpg");

    //selenium.type("q", "Hello world");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    BufferedImage image2 = Screenshot("screen2.jpg");

            public static BufferedImage Screenshot(String fileName) throws Exception
        {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
    return image;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the coordinates of your new bounds, create a new BufferedImage with the new size,  create a graphics object for your new image, and paint the big image on this graphics object, specifying negative values for the x,y. The source image is bigger than the destination, so only the bits that fit within the destination will be written. Then you save out the smaller one using ImageIO.write()

**EDIT**
Thanks to Andrew Thompson for the suggestion to use subImage

```
BufferedImage image1 = Screenshot("screen1.jpg");
BufferedImage subImage = image1.getSubImage(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: [BufferedImage.getSubimage(x,y,w,h)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is a quicker ('1 line') way to gain a crop of an image.

Comment: Edit that into the answer, and I can delete the noise.  ;)

Comment: "reate a graphics object for your new image"
Would you please elaborate on that part?